# Search behavior Individual/Household

Tags: search, search-results

I have a individual contact called: "John Wayne". 
He is connected to a household called "John and Margret Wayne".

When I search now for "John Wayne" in the simple search an in the advanced search, it only returns the household. Is this a normal behavior? Our NGO workers get super confused about this, is there a way to get the individual and household contact in the result table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get this work. I don't know if it's quite a hack, but it works at least.

Change this line in the "CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php": public function sortName(&$values):

```
if ($fieldName == 'sort_name') {
$wc = self::caseImportant($op) ? "LOWER(contact_a.sort_name)" : "contact_a.sort_name";
} else {
$wc = self::caseImportant($op) ? "LOWER(contact_a.display_name)" : "contact_a.display_name";
}
```

to:

```
  $wc = self::caseImportant($op) ? "LOWER(contact_a.sort_name)" : "contact_a.sort_name";
  $fieldsub[] = " ( $wc $op $value )";

  $wc = self::caseImportant($op) ? "LOWER(contact_a.display_name)" : "contact_a.display_name";
  $fieldsub[] = " ( $wc $op $value )";
```

Comment: If this is indeed a bug then please open a ticket in JIRA and try to provide a patch - https://issues.civicrm.org/jira

Answer (score 2):

It should show up both contacts, I suspect there might be something in the setup of your sort name. Could you attach some screen prints so I can see what happens?

Comment: When I search for "John Wayne" I get this result:
http://goga.ch/tmp/iogt/screen1.png

When I serach for "Wayne" this:
http://goga.ch/tmp/iogt/screen2.png

But if I check for "Wayne, John" I only get the Individual:
http://goga.ch/tmp/iogt/screen3.png

The settings for the sort name in the display preferences look like this:
http://goga.ch/tmp/iogt/screen4.png

Comment: @woistjadefox, what is your Automatic Wildcard set to?  (Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Search Preferences)

Comment: @AllenHutchison, it's set to "Yes". Tried it with "No" but it didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried your search on the demo site after adding your examples, and I get both contacts if I search for John Wayne in both Advanced Search and Search Contacts.[image]

I think this is your desired behaviour?

Comment: Yes exactly. But what could be the reason that It doesn't show both on my installation? I didn't change anything in the sort name settings.

Comment: just tried the same on the demo of the CiviCRM v4.6 on Drupal version: http://d46.demo.civicrm.org

I can reproduce the behavior of my installation. On which demo site did you try it?

Comment: Concur with Mr Fox. searching "john wayne" on demo via QuickSearch, Find, or Adv Search all return a single result of the household, whereas searching for just "wayne" returns both results

Comment: I tried on the 4.5 demo, so it smells like a 4.6 bug?

Comment: Argh.. any idea in which modul/file I could fix this my-self?